# powerwake is attempting to wake up an incorrect MAC addres

Tags: networking, server

When attempting to wake a remote machine (ubuntu server) from my laptop using `powerwake host01.cluster` I get a message back saying:

```
INFO: Trying to wake host: [host01.cluster]
INFO: Sending magic packet to: [xxxxxxxxxxxx]
```

Unfortunately, `xxxxxxxxxxxx` is an incorrect MAC address, and hence no remote waking up of the remote machine occurs.

When I try using the IP address (`powerwake 192.168.1.101`) it also sends the magic packet to the wrong MAC address.

I have the following line in `/etc/hosts/`

```
192.168.1.101   host01.cluster  host01
```

However, I can `ssh` into the machine using both `ssh host01`, and `ssh host01.cluster`. I'm assuming `/etc/hosts`, which I have set up for static addresses (on my laptop) is being used here for resolution.

When reading through `man powerwake` it provides a hierarchy of which caches it searches to resolve names:

1. `/var/cache/powerwake/ethers`
2. `/etc/ethers`
3. or the arp table (`arp -n`)

On my laptop (`uname -r` -> `4.2.0-35-generic`), bullet list item 1 is *empty*, 2 *doesn't exist*, and the incorrect MAC address doesn't even exist in the `arp -n` table either.

If I run `sudo arp-scan -l` on my laptop the incorrect MAC address doesn't show up there either.

Running `sudo find /var/cache/ -type f -exec grep -il "host01" {} \;` turns up no results either.

**Where else could a MAC address be cached buy ubuntu/`powerwake`?**

I would like to be able to purge the incorrect MAC address so that I can use `powerwake` to wake up this particular machine remotely.

`sudo ethtool eth0` run on the remote shows that WOL is enabled.

```
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: 1000Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 1
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: off (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went digging through `/usr/bin/powerwake` (just a python script) and I found a reference to `"%s/.cache/ethers"`, so I looked in my home directory ,and sure enough, this file was present (`cat ~/.cache/ethers`) that wasn't part of `man powerwake`.

This file held the incorrect reference for the IP address -> MAC address mapping that was causing the issue.

## Solution

Anyway, I deleted the file `~/.cache/ethers`, then "warmed" this cache file again.

## Warm the powerwake cache

First I checked my `arp` table, as I had since cleared it, to see what was in there. None of the remotes I wanted to contact were listed, so I performed a simple `ping -c 2 192.168.1.XXX` on each machine I wished to wake (the remote machines need to be on and able to be pinged). This loaded them into the arp table (confirmed by `arp -n`).

I then ran:

- `powerwake 192.168.1.XXX` for each machine
- `powerwake hostXX` for each machine again
- This allowed the `~/.cache/ethers` file to be loaded with each entry that matches my `/etc/hosts` file on my laptop
- Run `cat ~/.cache/ethers` to confirm the file exists and has been populated with the correct IP Addr -> MAC mapping